# How to add a water mark over existing content such as images/shapes in pdf?

Tags: c#, itext

I am adding a water mark in pdf using iTextSharp. My code works fine and adds a water mark successfully. But in some cases I hide this water mark with a rectangluar shape and run this code again to add new water mark on the same place in the same file, having the old water mark under the rectangular shape.
The problem is my new water mark also goes under that shape and becomes invisible. My code is given below. Please guide me to fix this issue.

```
//Add watermark
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfFile))
{
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(outpdfFile, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        PdfContentByte over = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

        iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font();
        font.Size = 20;
        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(over, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase("This is water mark over existing content", font), 200, 500, 0);

    }
}
```

Comment: I've removed the ASP.NET tag from your question because there is no relationship with your question. I've also removed the tags from your question title as their use went against the site's tagging guidelines.

Comment: You say you *hide this water mark with rectangluar shape*. Do you mean a square annotation? Or do you draw that rectangle on the `OverContent` just like the watermark?

Comment: Hi, can you add a sample input PDF to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.